# Create new df column from dictionary value on matching key

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

Given the DataFrame `df` and dictionary `test_dict`:

```
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize data of lists.
data = {'ref':['Gfg', 'Gfg', 'Gfg', 'Gfg', 'isR', 'Qst', 'jPu'],
    'position':[1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, np.nan]}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   ref  position
0  Gfg       1.0
1  Gfg       3.0
2  Gfg       1.0
3  Gfg       1.0
4  isR       2.0
5  Qst       1.0
6  jPu       NaN

test_dict = {"Gfg" : [5, 3, 6], "isR" : [8, 4], "Qst" : [10, 11]}
```

I am trying to create a new column in `df` by matching `df.ref` item against dictionary key and then returns the value from the paired list in `test_dict` based on value in `df.position`

This would produce the following:

```
   ref  position  new_col
0  Gfg       1.0      5
1  Gfg       3.0      6
2  Gfg       1.0      5
3  Gfg       1.0      5
4  isR       2.0      4
5  Qst       1.0      10
6  jPu       NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

`map` `test_dict` to "ref" column and use a list comprehension to iterate over the lists in each row and index them using "position":

```
df['new_col'] = [lst if isinstance(lst, float) else lst[int(i)-1] for i, lst in zip(df['position'], df['ref'].map(test_dict))]
```

Output:

```
   ref  position  new_col
0  Gfg       1.0      5.0
1  Gfg       3.0      6.0
2  Gfg       1.0      5.0
3  Gfg       1.0      5.0
4  isR       2.0      4.0
5  Qst       1.0     10.0
6  jPu       NaN      NaN
```